# Package installation by selecting moudle

Tags: managed-package, package, package-install

Is Salesforce provide any way to install the package by selecting module?
Example - I have a managed package and it contains two module like A and B.
Is there any to customize the package installation process so that we can install it by selecting module A or module B or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You will need to create 2 different packages for different installations

Comment: Thanks, It seems that Salesforce doesn't provide any configuration change to select module/components while installation of the package.

Comment: you are right. this can be done though inside your package - you can supply a configuration VF page that will configure what would be available, and on the other hand develop your package to support these settings

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it by using configuration VF page and manage module availability on the basis of configuration.